# Is Collections.binarySearch(list,key)*-2 is lower_bound for key when key not found in java List?

Tags: java, collections, binary-search, lower-bound, upperbound

Consider the following code .

```java
  List<Integer> list = new Random().ints(10,1,50).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        list.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.print("Enter key :");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int key = sc.nextInt();
        int ans = Collections.binarySearch(list, key);

        String result = String.format("ans = %d, list.at(ans*-1) = %d , lower bond = %d , upper bound = %d ", ans,list.get(ans*-1),list.get(ans*-1 -2 ) , 
                list.get(ans * -1 -1));
        System.out.println(result);
```

I was working on binarySearch method given by Collections class. When key does not present in list, it gives these weird numbers in negative. I mapped them to their lower bound and upper bound. I worked on several examples and always got it right.

> see this

[image: screenshot]

For every input I have given it return correct upper bound and lower bound inside the list.
Can Anyone explain to me ? Whats happening inside the hood ?

Comment: Did you ever consider reading [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch-java.util.List-T-)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct and documented behavior of the [`Collections.binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch-java.util.List-T-). From the JavaDoc:

> the index of the search key, if it is contained in the list; otherwise, (-(insertion point) - 1). The insertion point is defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the list: the index of the first element greater than the key, or list.size() if all elements in the list are less than the specified key. **Note that this guarantees that the return value will be >= 0 if and only if the key is found.**

Note the last sentence (emphasized by myself), that there is guaranteed the return value is 0 or positive if the key is found. This implies that a negative value is returned if the required element is not present in the input `List`.

---

**Edit:** The negative value is actually *not that unpredictable* as it looks like. Browsing the source code of [`java.util.Collections`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java) and its private methods calculating the result ...

- `Collections.indexedBinarySearch` from the line `278`
- `Collections.iteratorBinarySearch` from the line `298`

... both of them return the following in case the key was not found:

```
return -(low + 1);  // key not found
```

Therefore the returned value is the negative index of where the searched element was *expected to be located at*.

Comment: It's funny that you cite a documentation which says that the negative value is `(-(insertion point) - 1)`, right in the first sentence and then, have to browse the source code  to find that it is `-(low + 1)` (which is identical to `-low - 1`)...

Comment: Although I am having some trust issues in JavaDoc, I believe the algorithm calculation results `low` in `insertion point`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "trust issues in JavaDoc". This documentation is the method's specification. If the method did something different, the implementation was broken. But you can trust a widely used 22 year old implementation to do what has been specified.